# Split string by ',' into array except ',' within ()

Tags: c#, string, split

I am having string like

```
"11,Standard(db=S,api=Standard),UI,1(db=1,api=STANDARD),Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36,1010,9999,1000,9998.0,,1"
```

I would like to split it by char ',' but i don't like to include ',' within the '()'. Please help how to split such string in c#.
Ignore char ',' within ().

Output should be like:

```
   array of string = [ 
     "11", 
     "Standard(db=S,api=Standard)", 
     "UI", 
     "1(db=1,api=STANDARD)", 
     "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36", 
     "1010"
```

etc.

Comment: You need a parser. You should be able to write one, just read one characted at a time and keep the state around to see if you're within `()` or not.

Comment: Anything like regex?

Comment: What are you going to do in case of nested `x(a,b(c,d),e)`?

Comment: You'd better show what output of this operation do you expect... What it should be for case mentioned in @DmitryBychenko's question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the pattern is **always** that you can use a RegularExpression in order to split on the delimiters (commas) than to match the tokens. Identifying the commas that are delimiters takes a relatively simple:

```
",(?=[^\)]*(?:\(|$))"
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GgboVn

Explanation: http://regexr.com/3bgfj

Comment: this matches the `,` in `foo (,()) foo`

Answer (score 3):

here is a parser

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Parse(string Input)
{
    int depth = 0;
    StringBuilder Line = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char item in Input)
    {
        if (depth == 0 && item == ',')
        {
            yield return Line.ToString();
            Line = new StringBuilder();
        }
        else
        {
            Line.Append(item);
            if (item == '(')
            {
                depth++;
            }
            if (item == ')')
            {
                depth--;
            }
        }
    }
    if (Line.Length > 0)
        yield return Line.ToString();
}
```

useage:

```
var result = Parse(input);
```

Comment: It seems, that `StringBulider` will be a better type for `Line` than `string`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - updated. anyway shouldn't be that big difference for such short strings

Comment: actually, we *don't know* the *actual* string (or strings) lengths. Often, such parsers are used to scan logs, journals etc. to find, if, say, Mozilla is mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple and straightforward parser. Not bullet proof and depending on your needs it might need some modifications:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var toSplit = "11,Standard(db=S,api=Standard),UI,1(db=1,api=STANDARD),Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36,1010,9999,1000,9998.0,,1";

        var list = new List<string>();
        var isInside = 0;
        var currentPart = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < toSplit.Length; i++)
        {
            var chr = toSplit[i];

            switch (chr)
            {
                case ',':
                    if(isInside == 0)
                    {
                        list.Add(currentPart);
                        currentPart = string.Empty;
                    }
                    break;

                case '(':                        
                    isInside++;
                    currentPart += chr;
                    break;

                case ')':
                    isInside--;
                    currentPart += chr;
                    break;

                default:
                    currentPart += chr;
                    break;
            }
        }

        foreach (var part in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(part);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I would use `StringBuilder` instead of string concatenation, but it's pretty much what OP should do.

Comment: Indeed, @MarcinJuraszek, that would be the first (and mandatory) improvement.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. It'll split you input at `delimitter` outsinde of any Parenthesis

```
static IEnumerable<string> SplitStringMyWay(string text, char delimitter)
{
    string[] internalItems = text.Split(delimitter);
    List<string> theItems = new List<string>();
     string newItem = string.Empty;
    int openParenthesis = 0;
     foreach (string item in internalItems)
    {
        if (openParenthesis != 0) newItem += ",";
         newItem += item;
        openParenthesis += GetCharCount('(', item);
        openParenthesis -= GetCharCount(')', item);
         if (openParenthesis == 0)
        {
            theItems.Add(newItem);
          newItem = string.Empty;
        }
    }
     return theItems;
}
static int GetCharCount(char value, string text)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (char character in text)
    {
        if (character == value)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
     return count;
}
```

Code is not testet and can include errors. If you find one feel free to edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

IMO the simplest way is to first split your string using `','` and then concatenate strings with'(' and ')' signs together :

```
string value = @"11,Standard(db=S,api=Standard),UI,1(db=1,api=STANDARD),Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36,1010,9999,1000,9998.0,,1";

List<string> list = new List<string>();

string[] temp = value.Split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < value.Split(',').Length; i++) { if (temp[i].Contains('(')) continue; if (temp[i].Contains(')')) { list.Add(temp[i - 1] + temp[i]); continue; } list.Add(temp[i]); }

foreach (var item in list) Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Output:

```
11
Standard(db=S,api=Standard)
UI
1(db=1,api=STANDARD)
```

P.S.
Of course you can write your parser too :

```
    static string[] MySplit(string dirty, char delimiter = ',', string ignoreInside = "()")
    {            
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        bool sectionStarted = false;
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dirty.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!sectionStarted && dirty[i] == delimiter) 
            {
                result.Add(sb.ToString());
                sb.Clear(); continue; 
            }

            if (ignoreInside.Contains(dirty[i])) sectionStarted = dirty[i] == ignoreInside[0];                 
            sb.Append(dirty[i]);
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

Usage : `var result = MySplit(value);`

Output is the same as in example above.

Answer (score 0):

This is works

```
 var values = "11,Standard(db=S,api=Standard),UI,1(db=1,api=STANDARD),Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36,1010,9999,1000,9998.0,,1";
 var splitList = GetSplitList(values);



 public static List<string> GetSplitList(string values)
    {
        var splitList = new List<string>();
        var retValue = string.Empty;
        foreach (var value in values.Split(','))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(retValue) && !value.Contains(")"))
            {
                retValue += string.Format("{0},", value);
                continue;
            }
            if (value.Contains("("))
            {
                retValue += string.Format("{0},", value);
                continue;
            }
            if (value.Contains(")"))
            {
                retValue += value;
                splitList.Add(retValue);
                retValue = string.Empty;
                continue;
            }
            splitList.Add(value);
        }
        return splitList;

    }
```